# Routing in Asp.Net 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have successfully setup routing in Asp.Net 4.0 webforms. I have set up:

```
  routeCollection.MapPageRoute("Default Page", "Default/{ProductName}/{CategoryName}", "~/Default.aspx");
```

However, problem is even though the user browses to default.aspx, the page still shows up. How can I avoid this? I want only the MapPageRoute to work. I want that when user browses to default.aspx some error should be thrown or 404 page should be shown etc. In short I do not the user to browse through default.aspx. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can handle this issue through two ways.

1. In global.asax in Request_Start event check that if the requested url end by .aspx redirect to error page.
2. Use Url rewriter, by regular expression identify the wrong requests and redirect them to custom error page.

[image]

Comment: By Urlrewriter you mean `http://urlrewriter.net/` ? I have limited experience with this. But if this link is correct I can start studying it myself.

Comment: If you're using IIS7 + you can use the URL Rewrite Module. http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: You can check http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite. you can create rule via IIS7 or web config. Do you need a sample?

Comment: @Peyman: If you have it I will be glad to accept it. It may help me :)

Comment: @Phill: What if I am using Cassini and not IIS? Do I need to host in IIS 7.5 only? I don't have any problem but just for information I need to know :)

Comment: @Bob - I'm really not sure why you would need/want to run Cassini, the module only runs on IIS7+. If you want to achieve url-rewriting in IIS6, and (i don't know if it works or not) Cassini. Then you will need to use the module from www.urlrewriter.net or www.urlrewriting.net

Comment: @Phil: Thanks! I just wanted to get little info about Cassini.

Comment: @Bob: You can use the Cassini if you set up the rule in your web config.

Answer (score -1):

Never used routing in WebForms myself, but have you tried looking at the Request.Url? If that ends with/contains you could handle this by redirecting to an error page.

Comment: I know this approach but isn't there any declarative and better way of doing this?

Comment: Peyman's Url rewriting approach then seems to me as a viable option.